# get triggered with addJavascriptInterface when new content added to current page

Tags: javascript, android, webview

i'm trying to add some new content to current loaded html (in `webview`), this is not the problem, i can add new tag to body via `javascript`, suppose this:

```
loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.body.innerHTML += '<div id=\"separator\" style=\"height:10px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; background-color:#000000;\"></div> <p><font size=24> static page " + pageNumber + "';}())");
```

it do the job fine.

**but i want to know when the new content rendered and showed to user.** (i used below way but if you know better way tell me please). so i added a `javascript` interface like this:

```
addJavascriptInterface(new ObjectExtension(), "webviewScriptAPI");

final class ObjectExtension
{
    public void onLoad()
    {
        Log.i("onLoad", "onLoad get called");       
    }
}
```

now i try to load first html page via `loadUrl("local html address");`

when the page loaded completly, i want to add new content via javascript and call the `onLoad()` when the new content rendered, so i add this:

```
loadUrl("javascript:(function() { window.onload = function() { webviewScriptAPI.onLoad(); }; })()");
loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.body.innerHTML += '<div id=\"separator\" style=\"height:10px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; background-color:#000000;\"></div> <p><font size=24> static page " + pageNumber + "';}())"); // pageNumber is an incremental integer
```

the new content add successfully but the `onLoad()` did not get triggered.

i also tried this, with no success:

```
loadUrl("javascript:(function() { window.onresize = function() { webviewScriptAPI.onLoad(); }; })()");
loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.body.innerHTML += '<div id=\"separator\" style=\"height:10px; margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px; background-color:#000000;\"></div> <p><font size=24> static page " + pageNumber + "';}())"); // pageNumber is an incremental integer
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, i solved it via `document.ready`

```
loadUrl(html);
loadUrl("javascript:(function() { if(document.readyState === \"complete\") { webviewScriptAPI.onLoad(); }; })()");
```

Answer (score 0):

There's one line missing in:

```
final class ObjectExtension
{
    public void onLoad()
    {
        Log.i("onLoad", "onLoad get called");       
    }
}
```

it should be:

```
final class ObjectExtension
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void onLoad()
    {
        Log.i("onLoad", "onLoad get called");       
    }
}
```